# Django cannot find template stored at app_name/templates/app_name

Tags: django, django-templates

I'm trying to build a recipe website. I have two apps, `account` (user auth stuff) and `recipe`. The templates for `account` are stored in `account/templates/registration`. Django can find these without a problem, my login, logout, register, etc views are working without an issue. However, in my recipe app I have one simple view so far:

```
def index(request):
    return render(request, 'recipe/index.html')
```

This file exists at `recipe/templates/recipe/index.html`. When I try to access it I get the following error:

```
Django tried loading these templates, in this order:

Using engine django:

django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader: /Users/justinobrien/Desktop/recipeSite/website/templates/index.html (Source does not exist)
django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: /Users/justinobrien/Desktop/recipeSite/website/account/templates/index.html (Source does not exist)
django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: /Users/justinobrien/Desktop/recipeSite/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/crispy_forms/templates/index.html (Source does not exist)
django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: /Users/justinobrien/Desktop/recipeSite/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/templates/index.html (Source does not exist)
django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: /Users/justinobrien/Desktop/recipeSite/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/templates/index.html (Source does not exist)
```

It is clear it is not looking at the right path, I am just not sure how to tell it to look there?

I also made a change to the `DIRS` part of the `TEMPLATES` variable, so that Django could find the base.html file I have stored at `project_root/templates/base.html`:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

I am thinking that might be causing an issue. Thanks for any help.

Comment: how does INSTALLED_APPS look in your settings

Comment: @iklinac I am sorry for wasting your time, recipe app wasn't registered... However, I was able to run `def index(request):
    return HttpResponse('Hello world')` without an issue so I had assumed it was already registered? (I know it wouldn't have hurt to look)

Comment: no worries, this is why I asked if it is in installed apps as you can see there is no loader for recipe app in traceback